# How to calculate between hours from current date to pickupdate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.5

How to calculate between hours from current date to pickupdate. I have pickup date and pickup Time from Input. below function returns wrong value.

```
$bookingtime=strtotime($request->input('pickupdate_submit')." ".$request->input('pickuptime_submit') );

        $curentdate=date('Y-m-d HH:i');
        $curenttime=strtotime($curentdate);

        $betweenhours = abs($bookingtime - $curenttime) / 3600;
```

Comment: Try: `$date = Carbon::parse($request->input('pickupdate_submit')." ".$request->input('pickuptime_submit'));  $date->diff($curentdate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Carbon for this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($request->input('pickupdate_submit')." ".$request->input('pickuptime_submit'));

$hours = $date->diffInHours(Carbon::now());
```

In Laravel 5.5 it's recommended to import Carbon like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```